# How can i use css frameworks without cluttering html with too many classes

Tags: html, css

I want to use css framework but there are too many classes that will have no meaning in my html semantic please help me how can i use it with out using too many classes. I dont want to clutter my html with unmeaningful css class.

Comment: Your question is way too broad to answer properly. Please have a read through [ask], including all the links from that page, and enhance your question.

Comment: I know how you feel, but the answer is you can't use a framework without the framework - a framework comes with lots of classes.  You can try to find a very minimal grid-layout css to plug in if you are doing responsive design but using a framework implies lots of code!

Comment: Is there any way i can import only classes i want from framework using less or sass into my classes?

Comment: @SandeepSharma You can import only certain classes by using your text editor's "Find..." function, searching for the classes you want, and moving them to a separate CSS file that you use. It's also possible to import the framework normally but not use any of its classes except the ones you need, but this will effect page load times a lot depending on the size of the framework.

Comment: You may want to look into how to use @extend, mixins, etc. With a css preprocessor, adding non semantic classes to your html is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the SASS or LESS versions of the frameworks.

Then your HTML might look like

```
<section class="foo"><article class="bar">...</article></section>
```

and your SASS would look like:

```
.foo {
    @extend %row;
}
.bar {
    @extend %col-md-6;
}
```

Maybe you'd be using mixins instead of abstract classes, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your best shot in this case is to use only modules you need (e.g. grids, components, etc). All the biggest framework such as Bootstrap, PureCSS etc. let you do that.

Then just take use the classes you really need from there (DO NOT change the core of these frameworks).

I would also suggest to read SMACSS for way on how to keep your specifity low and your names constant.

Comment: +1 for _DO NOT change the core of these frameworks_. It's a real hassle as the next guy to come along and work with it.

Comment: yh have been there, not funny at all